# Drag a item from drawer and complete it in main page flutter

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, drawer

I would like to drag a item from left side drawer and need to leave it in the main page as the Draggable and DragTarget is need to be in same widget we need to write the Draggable in one widget and DragTarget in another widget`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () =>
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(), // <-- Opens drawer.
        );
      }),
      body: Center(child: Text("Need to drop here from drawer")),
      drawer: Drawer(
        width: 200,
        child: Column(children: [
          Draggable(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
            feedback: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
            childWhenDragging: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
            onDragStarted: () => {debugPrint("Drag Starts")},
            onDragEnd: (details) => {debugPrint("Drag End")},
            onDragCompleted: () => {debugPrint("Drag Completed")},
          ),
          DragTarget<String>(builder: (
            BuildContext context,
            List<dynamic> accepted,
            List<dynamic> rejected,
          ) {
            return Container(
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                ));
          })
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

Expected output:

[image]

Please suggest a solution

Tried creating a Draggable and DragTarget in same widget. This works like as expected